# Javascript: Defining a map of functions

Tags: javascript

```
$("#searchType").on('change', function () {
    var selectionAction = {
        All: loadAll(),
        Competitions: loadAll("competitions"),
        Clubs: loadAll("clubs"),
        Teams: loadAll("teams")
    };
    var selection = $("#searchType").find('option:selected').val();
    selectionAction[selection]
});
```

See the above code. The idea is that when selection equals one of the properties in my object, then the corresponding function will be called.

e.g. when selection equals `Competitions` then we would invoke `loadAll("competitions")` function.

Instead what I am finding is that when it enters the `onChange` function that it invokes all functions.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Whenever you have `()` after a function reference, the function gets called. `All: loadAll(),` calls the function `loadAll` and assigns the return value to the property `All`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use anonymous functions to make the call. Currently you are storing the result of the function call which is undefined

```
var selectionAction = {
    All: function(){loadAll()},
    Competitions: function(){loadAll("competitions")},
    Clubs: function(){loadAll("clubs")},
    Teams: function(){loadAll("teams")}
};
var selection = $("#searchType").find('option:selected').val();
selectionAction[selection]();// make sure to call the anonymous function
```

Or, if you prefer brevity,

```
$("#searchType").on('change', function () {
 loadAll($("#searchType").find('option:selected').val().replace("All","").toLowerCase())
});
```

Comment: you can use bind() instead of anons for all these. nothing wrong here, just saying...

Comment: @dandavis - yup, I had considered that as well as an option. It is a preference to be sure, I tend to not use bind when I am not taking advantage of the `this` context.

Answer (score 2):

When you specify `loadAll()`, `loadAll("competitions")`, `loadAll("clubs")` and so on you are actually executing the function immediately. What you want to do is have your object have properties of non-function calls like so:

```
 var selectionAction = {
    All: '',
    Competitions: 'competitions',
    Clubs: 'clubs',
    Teams: 'teams'
  };
```

And then do:

```
var selection = $("#searchType").find('option:selected').val();
loadAll(selectionAction[selection]);
```

And make sure your `loadAll` function checks for existence of its 1st argument.